# What theme variable addresses the thickness of window resize handles?

Tags: extjs

Using a theme that extends Triton, I find that the resize handles on instances of Ext.window.Window are 10px wide.  That thickness interferes with scrollbars (and maybe other things).  I cannot, however, figure out how what theme variable influences resize handle thickness.

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1fun

Comment: Could you provide us with some code and preferably even a fiddle?

Comment: Thanks.  I added a fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which version of Ext you're using, so hereby I assume you use 6.0.2. I found in the documentation there's a Resizer component that is used by several components including Window. Here's a link: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2-classic/Ext.resizer.Resizer.html

If you there look into the theme veriables you'll find this: $resizer-handle-size. By default this is set to the same width of $panel-frame-border-width. To override that you'll need to change the number in your sass yourself.

Hope this helps you out!

Comment: Indeed, setting `$resizer-handle-size` to 5px seems to solve to the issue. Thanks!